# JS анимация. Остается след

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, анимация

Здравствуйте. Надо нарисовать с помощью Canvas и JavaScript анимацию падающего примитива. Так вот. Как сделать так, чтобы он не оставлял предыдущее состояние?

Фрагмент кода

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
function draw()
{
  var y = 0;

  function frame()
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100+y, 20, 0, 2*3.14);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    y+=5;
    if (y >= 100) clearTimeout(timer);

  }
  var timer = setInterval(frame, 50);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200>
</canvas>
```

Могу предоставить весь код, если надо.
То, что получилось:

[image: Результат работы.]

Comment: `setInterval` ... `clearTimeout` - баг.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно поподробнее?

Comment: Это не по теме баг. А по теме - надо очищать всё отрисованное и рисовать заново. Либо использовать метод сохранения отрисованного и его восстановления.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как можно сохранять и восстанавливать? `ctx.save(); ctx.restore()` ?

Comment: Нет. Эта пара сохраняет параметры контекста, но не рисунок. Есть другая.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда какая?

Comment: Не помню, надо искать. Но она есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я найти не могу в гугле.

Comment: Я тоже :( Попозже посмотрю в других местах. Если найду, напишу ответ.

Comment: Можно создать второй слой поверх первого, и каждый раз полностью стирать второй слой и прорисовывать там заново на новом месте. Тогда и восстанавливать в первом слое не придется и производительность соответственно будет выше.

Comment: @zhenyab как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Слои можно реализовать путем наложения канвасов один на другой, как вариант использования одного канваса посмотрите эту библиотеку: https://bitbucket.org/ant512/canvaslayers/wiki/Home

Comment: @zhenyab ещё проблема заключается в том, что использовать сторонние библиотеки не желательно.

Comment: наложи несколько прозрачных канвасов друг на друга и работай только с тем который нужно

Comment: @Den Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Den, всё проще же.

Comment: @Qwertiy интересный подход, для этого вопроса подойдёт но... 2 проблемы: 1 - setInterval 2 - getImageData и putImageData. В сумме производительность будет ужасной. Попозже нарисую ещё 1-н ответ.

Comment: @Den, `setInterval` я просто не трогал, по-хорошему, надо бы `requestAnimationFrame`. Если имелось в виду заполнение очереди, то это миф. А вот про `putImageData` не согласен - полагаю, это эффективнее, чем заново перерисовывать картинку. У канваса проблем с производительностью обычно нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `getImageData` позволяет запомнить отображённую картинку, а `putImageData` - восстановить её:

```js
~function () {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  function draw() {
    var y = 0;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

    var state = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    function frame() {
      ctx.putImageData(state, 0, 0);
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.arc(100, 100+y, 20, 0, 2*3.14);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();

      y+=5;
      if (y >= 100) clearInterval(timer);
    }

    var timer = setInterval(frame, 50);
  }

  draw();
}();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=230>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Вроде всё работает с этим кодом. Спасибо.